# Is there any way to automatically choose correct read.csv parameters?

Tags: r, csv

I have a number of CSV files with slightly different file format - like extra columns could be added (which I don't need), header could be there or not, time format could be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` or `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`. Is there any way to do some pre-analysis of csv file to choose then correct parameters for `read.csv`?

For ex., I have the following logics used to read files:

```
# file 1
dataft <- read.csv("file1.csv", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor"))
dataft[,"ddate"] = as.Date(dataft[,"ddate"],"%Y-%m-%d")

# file 2
datagae <- read.csv("file2.csv", header = FALSE, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor"), col.names = c("col1", "col2", "ddate", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13"))
datagae[,"ddate"] = as.Date(datagae[,"ddate"],"%Y%m%d")

# file 3 (with extra column, which I don't need - not sure how to skip it, NULL doesn't help)
datagae <- read.csv("file3.csv", header = FALSE, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", NULL), col.names = c("col1", "col2", "ddate", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13", ""))
datagae[,"ddate"] = as.Date(datagae[,"ddate"],"%Y%m%d")
```

(all data frames will be merged once loaded)

**Upd**. files samples (number of possible file formats is limited (and known)!) -

```
# file 1
or,d,ddate,rdate,changes,class,price,fdate,company,number,minutes,added,source
VA1,VA2,2014-05-24,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:50:16,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,tp
VA1,VA2,2014-05-26,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:03:44,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,tp
VA1,VA2,2014-06-05,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:48:24,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,tp
VA1,VA2,2014-06-09,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:37:35,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,tp
VA1,VA2,2014-06-16,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 14:17:33,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,tp

# file 2    
VA2,VA4,20140722,,0,3,6164,20140521121156,U1,U141,140,20140521121156,ms
VA3,VA5,20140701,,0,0,15176,20140521145035,S1,S1342,355,20140521145035,ms
VA3,VA6,20140710,,0,0,6676,20140521105118,S1,S1602,105,20140521105118,ms
VA2,VA7,20140729,,0,0,10023,20140521132150,U6,U100,230,20140521132150,ms
VA2,VA5,20140527,,0,0,13209,20140521145005,S7,S115,355,20140521145005,ms

# file 3
VA8,VA3,20140929,,0,0,14571,20140603163257,S1,S233,390,20140603163421,ms,4503623383908352
VA9,VA0,20140611,,0,0,13329,20140603171428,U6,U355,165,20140603171553,ms,4503639892688896
VA2,VA4,20140722,,0,3,6164,20140521121156,U1,U141,140,20140521121156,ms,4503659220041728
VA3,BAX,20140601,,0,0,14176,20140525101531,S1,S1430,250,20140525101608,ms,4503686600458240
VA3,REN,20140602,,0,0,10174,20140531213527,S1,S1244,121,20140531213653,ms,4503703511891968

# file 4   
or,added,key,source,price,d,av_s,type,number,company,class,changes,minutes,fdate,ddate,code
VA2,20140808T122044,VA2:VA9:20140808::0:0:14430:20140808122044,qE,14430,VA9,2,319,6156,S1,0,0,90,20140808T122044,20140808T192500,B
VA2,20140808T122044,VA2:VA9:20140808::0:0:19180:20140808122044,qE,19180,VA9,2,319,6182,S1,0,0,90,20140808T122044,20140808T222000,Y
VA2,20140808T122044,VA2:VA9:20140808::0:1:14866:20140808122044,qE,14866,VA9,1,319,41,S7,1,0,100,20140808T122044,20140808T203500,D
VA2,20140808T122045,VA2:VA9:20140808::0:1:35180:20140808122045,qE,35180,VA9,2,319,6146,S1,1,0,90,20140808T122045,20140808T171000,C
VA2,20140808T122044,VA2:VA9:20140809::0:0:3180:20140808122043,qE,3180,VA9,2,319,6186,S1,0,0,95,20140808T122043,20140809T232000,N

# file 5
data,key
"VA1,VA2,20140524,,0,0,5969,20140523134902,S7,S1147,140,20140523134902,m/t",4503632376496128
"VA2,VA3,20140711,,0,0,8824,20140601095714,S1,S6402,175,20140601095839,m/t",4503643113914368
"VA1,VA3,20140710,,0,0,11678,20140604085203,S1,S1430,250,20140604085329,m/t",4503666467799040
"VA2,VA1,20140724,,0,0,7109,20140523133835,S7,S793,130,20140523133835,m/t",4503679218483200
"VA3,VA1,20140925,,0,0,10592,20140604092548,S7,S109,395,20140604092714,m/t",4503694653521920
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you expect R to read your mind? Maybe `fread` from package data.table could be helpful. But you probably need to do some post-processing after data import instead of the "pre-analysis" you are suggesting.

Comment: @Roland, using some other language I can try to read first line of the file and then (1) check if it is header of not (by presence of some words there), (2) detect date formatting, (3) check number of columns. Knowing this data, I know how to read the file. The question is if I can do the same with R.

Comment: *After* loading the data (with date as character) you could try `lubridate::ymd()`, which IIRC tries a variety of heuristics to guess the date format. Could we have  reproducible example?

Comment: @BenBolker, I've added files samples

Comment: The easiest way would be to put every file type in a separate directory and let R read every dir in a different way. Or using that other language (AWK by any change?), you could make a text file that tells R how to read each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came to the following solution:

```
fileCSV <- "file.csv"
conn <- file(fileCSV, "rt")
file <- readLines(conn, n = 1) # read only first line
fileFormat <- NULL
if (file[1]=="or,d,ddate,rdate,changes,class,price,fdate,company,number,minutes,added,source") {
    fileFormat <- 1

    data <- read.csv(fileCSV, header = TRUE, colClasses = c("factor", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor"))
    data[,"ddate"] = as.Date(dataft[,"ddate"],"%Y-%m-%d")    
} else if (file[1]=="or,added,key,source,price,d,av_s,type,number,company,class,changes,minutes,fdate,ddate,code") {
    fileFormat <- 2

    # another approach to read the file
} else if (file[1]=="data,key") {
    fileFormat <- 3

    # third approach to read the file
} else if (grepl("[A-Z]{3},[A-Z]{3},20\\d{6},(20\\d{6})?,\\d,\\d,\\d+,20\\d{12}\\.*", file[1])[1] == TRUE && length(strsplit(file[1], ",")[[1]])==13) {
    fileFormat <- 4
} else if (grepl("[A-Z]{3},[A-Z]{3},20\\d{6},(20\\d{6})?,\\d,\\d,\\d+,20\\d{12}\\.*", file[1])[1] == TRUE && length(strsplit(file[1], ",")[[1]])==14) {
    fileFormat <- 5
}
```

First line is analyzed to identify file content and then read it properly.